# Collapse Accordion menu on next page onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have made an Accordion based menu in a menu.php.
Let's say 
**menu.php**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMenu" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">Test</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="/test/index.php">Take Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="/test/report.php">My Best Report</a></li>
        <li><a href="/test/repository.php">My Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="/test/about.php">About Test</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMenu" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">Training</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="/training/">Recommended Training</a></li>
        <li><a href="/training/purchased.php">Purchased Training</a></li>
        <li><a href="/training/other.php">Other Training</a></li>
        <li><a href="/training/about.php">About Training</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And on every other page I'm calling menu.php using `include("menu.php");`
Now I want the accordion to automatically open on next page when it's link is opened. How should I track which link is opened and activate that accordion tab ?

Comment: In your PHP, are you using the URI to know which page is displayed ?

Comment: No. Isn't there any easy way we can do with jquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try some jQuery to add class to the `li` and its parent when the pathname corresponds to the link:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns only path of URI
  var href_value;

  // Here, I force the pathname to be able to simulate
  // You won't need it in your application, but maybe some formatting
  pathname = "/training/purchased.php";

  // Loop for each li
  $(".nav li").each(function() {
    href_value = $(this).children("a").attr("href");

    // when "pathname" equals the href of the link
    if (pathname == href_value) {
      // Add "active" to li and "collapsed" to the menu
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $(this).closest(".collapse").addClass("collapsed");
    }

  })

});
```

```css
.active a {
  color: red;
}

.collapse {
  display: none;
}

.collapsed {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMenu" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">Test</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="/test/index.php">Take Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="/test/report.php">My Best Report</a></li>
        <li><a href="/test/repository.php">My Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="/test/about.php">About Test</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMenu" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">Training</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="/training/">Recommended Training</a></li>
        <li><a href="/training/purchased.php">Purchased Training</a></li>
        <li><a href="/training/other.php">Other Training</a></li>
        <li><a href="/training/about.php">About Training</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That's difficult to simulate on a snippet with the URLs…

Comment: Only class="active" won't make the accordion open. We also need to change the "collapse" class to "collapsed"

Comment: I am modifying my code but that's hard to simulate correctly with the URLs. I'll add "collapsed" soon.

Comment: @KamleshTiwari I added the "collapsed" on the "collapse" parent of the active `li`. I think it's where you want it to be, am I right ? :)

Comment: After messing around a little bit in this code I finally got what I needed. Thanks!